# Axios Post with foreign key of int

Tags: java, database, vue.js, post, axios

I have an project with the following specs:

Database:

```
Table: User
Columns: user_id, username, password
```

```
Table: Ticket
Columns: ticket_id, ticketname, ... , user_id
```

So user_id in the table Ticket is a foreign key.

Now, I am trying to do an axios POST like this;

```
insert(ticket) {
            return axios
                .post(API_URL + 'insertTicket', {
                        subject: ticket.subject,
                        issue: ticket.issue,
                        company: ticket.company,
                        date: datetime,
                        user: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'))["user"],
                }
                ,{headers: authHeader() })
            .then(response => {
                return response.data;
            });
        }
```

And this is my Ticket Entity:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "tickets")
public class Ticket {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "tickets_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "tickets_status")                        // 0 = geschlossen, 1 = offen, 2 = in Bearbeitung, 3 = geloescht
    private int status;

    @Column(name = "tickets_subject")
    private String subject;

    @Column(name = "tickets_issue")
    private String issue;

    @Column(name = "tickets_adddescription")
    private String adddescription;

    @Column(name = "tickets_steps")
    private String steps;

    @Column(name = "tickets_date")
    private String date;

    @Column(name = "tickets_company")
    private String company;

    @ManyToOne
    private User users;

    public Ticket(int status, String subject, String issue, String adddescription, String steps, String date, String company, User users) {
        this.status = status;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.issue = issue;
        this.adddescription = adddescription;
        this.steps = steps;
        this.date = date;
        this.company = company;
        this.users = users;
    }
}
```

There occurs the question: In the database the user_id is an int but in the Java Code it is the type of Entity: User.
How can I do the post to get the users id which i get from the JSON to the table Tickets?

Answer (score 0):

The body of your axios payload:

```
                {
                        subject: ticket.subject,
                        issue: ticket.issue,
                        company: ticket.company,
                        date: datetime,
                        user: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'))["user"],
                }
```

Has the prop names `subject, issue, company, date, user`
These do not directly match the prop names you have in your ticket entity
For example `(name = "tickets_id")`

I would suggest using [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) to test your axios POST before you write it in vuejs.  Run your tickets API and get the correct prop names and headers for your POST before putting it into vuejs and axios.

Comment: Well, subject, issue etc. are inserted into the database. There is not the issue. 
I think user is not posted because of the type. Thats why I am asking. @abbaf33f

Comment: Have you tried using Postman to get the payload correct first?  Perhaps the user object in JavaScript does not match the user object in your ticket entity.

Comment: That's what I am thinking: that they don't match. No I did not tried Postman. Can you explain how? @abbaf33f